# Why writing to file doesnt work?

Tags: c++, binary

I want to write a number in binary format to file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    uint16_t number = 2;
    ofstream data_to_save("saved_data.bin", ios_base::binary);
    data_to_save.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&number),sizeof(number));


    uint16_t numbers_16;
    ifstream data("saved_data.bin", ios_base::binary);
    data.seekg(0);
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&numbers_16), sizeof(numbers_16));
    cout << numbers_16 << "\n";

    data_to_save.close();
    data.close();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I read the file it is always zero. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Note: having to twist the arm of the type system and having to resort to `reinterpret_cast` is often a pretty good indicator that something is not quite right with your design.

Comment: You never check whether files are actually opened or whether writes and reads succeed. You didn't close output file before opening input file. This may lead to either data to be written being still in output file buffer or failure to open input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open "saved_data.bin" for read **before** the data was flushed into the file.